# Operator overload for object to be used in conditional statement

Tags: c++

How can I pass my object to an `if` statement and check if it is `true` or `false`

example:

```
struct A {
   int num;

   operator bool good() const {return num > 0;}
}

A a{1}; if(a) { /* it's all good man! */ }
```

I got inspired by `std::function` where you can [pass it into a if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) and it will return true if function pointer is set:

```
void checkFunc( std::function<void()> const &func )
{
    // Use operator bool to determine if callable target is available.
    if( func )  
    {
        std::cout << "Function is not empty! Calling function.\n";
        func();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Function is empty. Nothing to do.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is called *conversion to bool*. Or you might have heard about *conversion operator*. Search these terms and you'll find plenty of related SO posts. This is also covered in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Aha... I had no idea what it is called

Comment: what is a little puzzling is that you are mentioning operator overloading in the title, but then there is no operator overloading, and the answer to the question is ... operator overloading.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/4117728. Not sure if it is mentioned there, but note that `if` is a context where so called "contextual conversion to bool" takes place, ie the conversion operator can be `explicit` and will nevertheless be implicitly used when you write `if(func)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes I was a bit clumsy with this question. I updated question